Wrap list instead of scrolling to the right
List is not wrapping in browser, forced users to scroll to the right.
I have tried flex-wrap: wrap as well as display: flex;
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;  
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        li {
            background-color: #ffe8f9;
            /* Change background color of items to blue */
            color: #000000;
            /* Change text color of items to yellow */
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }


Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

This solution provides a clear and well-documented CSS (with HTML Markup) code that will help understand and customize the styles for list items and scrollbars effectively with comments in CSS for the scrollbar.


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap; /* use white-space nowrap */
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

li {
  background-color: #ffe8f9;
  /* Change background color of items to blue */
  color: #000000;
  /* Change text color of items to yellow */
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em; /* Set the width of the vertical scrollbar */
  height: .1875rem /* Set the height of the horizontal scrollbar */
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .375rem rgba(0,0,0,0.2) /* Add an inset shadow inside the scrollbar track */
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ccc; /* Change the color of the scrollbar thumb */
}
<ul>
  <li>List is not wrapping in browser, forced users to scroll to the right.</li>
  <li>I have tried flex-wrap: wrap as well as display: flex;</li>
  <li>I have tried flex-wrap: wrap as well as display: flex;</li>
  <li>I have tried flex-wrap: wrap as well as display: flex;</li>
  <li>I have tried flex-wrap: wrap as well as display: flex;</li>
</ul>



